# Exoplayer with android navigation bars

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

What should I do to show android navigation (top and bottom) bars when Exoplayer is hosted on the activity?

Below is my Activity XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.srushti.holmes.clipPlayActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_media_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#000000">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/exoplayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#757575"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Nothing"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And when activity is launched, this how the it appears

[image]

However, when I set `android:visibility="invisible"` to the SimpleExoPlayerView, navigation bar appears properly. What wrong am I doing here?

[image]

Here is the code written to launch the activity:

```
final Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, clipPlayActivity.class);
startActivity(playIntent);
```

Comment: The screenshot at the top seems to be in fullscreen mode while the one at the bottom is not. I'm not sure if this is only because you changed the visibility attribute only.

Comment: As you can see the XML, there is no where I am trying to set full screen mode. Not even in code behind. How come exo-player's visibility affect the activity's full screen mode? mystery!